# How to make the widget (ball) start on bottom of the screen - Python/Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make a basic visual exercise in Python and Kivy, but i'm stuck in this part of the code, how to make the ball start on the bottom of the screen?

Here's the .py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
    ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock


class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)


    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(0, 4)):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        # bounce ball off bottom or top or left or right
        if (self.ball.y < self.y) or (self.ball.top > self.top):
            self.ball.velocity_y = -2
            self.ball.velocity_x = -4

        # bounce ball off 
        if(self.ball.x < 0):
            self.ball.velocity_x  = 4
            self.ball.velocity_y  = 0

        if(self.ball.x + self.ball.width > self.right):
            self.ball.velocity_x *= -1
            self.ball.velocity_y  = 4

class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

.kv file:

```
<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50 
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size          

<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center
```

This code make the widget starts on center of the screen, i'm trying to make start on bottom, without success

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your case is that the `PongBall`'s initial position is the center of the `PongGame`:

```
<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center # <---
```

What you must do is that when you create the initial position is established. Another error is that you are launching the game before the window is displayed, instead of launching it in **build()** you must do it in `on_start()`:

***.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
    ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock


class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(0, 4)):
        self.ball.center = self.initial_pos
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        # bounce ball off bottom or top or left or right
        if self.ball.y < self.y or self.ball.top > self.top:
            self.ball.velocity_y = -2
            self.ball.velocity_x = -4

        # bounce ball off 
        if self.ball.x < 0:
            self.ball.velocity_x  = 4
            self.ball.velocity_y  = 0

        if self.ball.x + self.ball.width > self.right:
            self.ball.velocity_x *= -1
            self.ball.velocity_y  = 4

class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        return game

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.root.update, 1.0 / 60.0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

***.kv**

```
<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50 
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size          

<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball
    initial_pos: [self.center_x , pong_ball.height/2]
    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
```

In `build()` an incorrect size of the widgets is obtained since these are updated instants before being launched, it is convenient to use `on_start()` to obtain the size on which the initial position depends.

Comment: It works! Thank you for your help, i appreciate that